# Erratic iPhone behavior. Showing / hiding address bar behaves strange

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile-safari

Yesterday i had a problem with the mobile safari address bar.
It was refusing to retract ( slide up ).
But after adding a hash mark it started to work nicely.
Today however the address bar was strangely enough messed up again.
It does retract somewhat, but not completely. 10px or so is still dangling.
All variants of scrollTo(0,1) and window.location.href = '#' have been tried.
After all it seems like there is absolutely no logic that can defy the IOS Safari addressbar.
I have also tried to restart the phone, iPhone 4 IOS 6 without success.

Comment: Sometimes innerheight is about 16px short. It looks like the status bar height has been subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

I had added an overflow:hidden style property that caused the page height to measure i bit shorter than usual due to the trimmed of transparent excess height that i had before applying the overflow:hidden property.
The solution: I now add 60px to the body height manually to make space for the address bar to slide up. The downside is that it leaves a 60px blank space at the bottom of the screen if you scroll down.